# access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes) while connecting perl with mysql

Tags: mysql, perl

I had written a following perl script to connect with the mysql workbench database, but it is giving the error `access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)`.

Error after running the code:

```
C:\Users\1053130\Desktop>perl mysql.pl
DBI connect('database=dvd_collection','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at mysql.pl line 9.
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at mysql.pl line 9.
```

I have gone through the similar questions also, but according the these I already have `username` and `password`. I even changed the root password also. But the error is still the same.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use strict;
my $driver = "mysql"; 
my $database = "dvd_collection";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "123";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: On which OS you are working?

Comment: Can you connect to the database with those connection details using the `mysql` command line program?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt `my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";` rather be
`my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port";` ?

Missing the host and port?

**Edit:**
It says Access denied for... @localhost. Is it a local server? If not, you should declare the server-details as shown above.

**Edit2:**
According your comment you should check your password, as simple as it sounds. You can go for it with `mysql -u root -p newPasswordHere`. Choose a new one and retry.

**Edit3:**
As you already changed your password, try the following change of your connect:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:dbname=dvd_collection;host=localhost','root', '123') || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
```

I've seen some ppl having some issues with the different formats of the connection.

Comment: Yes, it is a local server. I tried by giving host/portal details also, still the error remains the same. @C4ud3x

Comment: Then you probably got the wrong password or you filtered out incoming connections from localhost.

Comment: Now the code is working without error by editing the code as you mentioned in Edit3. Thank you @C4ud3x

Comment: @swapnil90 you should accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the error says "the access is denied" then there are chances the password is wrong and in xampp server the dafault password to sql will be ' ' .hence just try the below line

```
my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:perldb",'root','') or die;
```